Why doesn't mathematica simplify the result of Norm in a Module calculation in this case?
I have a computation that involves the "contraction" of matrix and vector indices, see this question.
I am now running into a problem of simplification when using the expression as opposed to when simplifying the direct result of that expression. The Module statements I use to create the expression are:
vcalc[q_ : {_, _, _}, psi_ : {_, _}, phi_ : {_, _}] := 
  Module[{pm}, 
   psi . (# /. pm -> PauliMatrix) . phi & /@ 
    Cross[q, pm /@ Range[3]]];

and
neme[q_ : {_, _, _}, psi_ : {_, _}, phi_ : {_, _}, alpha_ : {_, _}, 
   beta_ : {_, _}] := 
  Module[{pm}, 
   alpha . (# /. pm -> PauliMatrix) . beta & /@ 
    Dot[pm /@ Range[3], Cross[q, vcalc[q, psi, phi]]]];

But when I use the expression like the following the answer is not simplified properly:
Simplify[Norm[neme[{q1, q2, q3}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]]^2, 
 Assumptions -> (Element[q1, Reals] && Element[q2, Reals] && 
    Element[q3, Reals])]

the result is:
Norm[(q1 - I q2)^2]^2

But, if I simplify this expression directly, I get the right thing:
Simplify[Norm[q1 - I q2]^4, 
 Assumptions -> (Element[q1, Reals] && Element[q2, Reals] && 
    Element[q3, Reals])]

this is the correct, simplified, real, result:
(q1^2 + q2^2)^2

As far as I can tell I am supplying all the necessary assumptions for what I want (that the components of q vector are real). Why will Mathematica not simplify the first expression correctly?

Use FullSimplify[Norm[neme[{q1, q2, q3}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]]^2 //  ComplexExpand, Assumptions -> (Element[q1, Reals] && Element[q2, Reals] && Element[q3, Reals])]

@BobHanlon can you explain the differences? As far as I can see ComplexExpand is sort of redundant, and I have never appreciated the difference between Simplify and FullSimplify... what you suggested worked though!

The ComplexExpand converts the Norm to Abs. There are apparently better simplifications built in for Abs. FullSimplify tries "harder" than Simplify and when possible should give better results, but is much slower.

@BobHanlon thanks, can confirm that removing ComplexExpand and switching Norm to Abs has the same effect in this case.
